# ZF3 - adding a view fragment to ViewModel

Tags: zend-framework3

I am curious to know if it is possible to add a fragment to a view model:

```
return new ViewModel([]);
```

Returns my view to https://example.com/view

However is it possible to set this dynamically to add a fragment?

```
return new ViewModel("#fragment")
```

To return to https://example.com/view#fragment

The use case, have a js login/register view that is either https://example.com/view#login or https://example.com/view#register and want to return to the correct view...

EDIT
Obviously, this can be done using a re-direct, however, in the case of returning form errors, ViewModel needs to be used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is possible to apply param to router, but you can alwas return redirectToRegister = true, and then write and execute JavaScript in view which will change view if True.

Answer (score 0):

A fragment is a [same document](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.4) reference i.e. if the URL specification is used correctly #register and #login will refer to different elements in the same document.

The view model therefore should be returning the same html in both cases, and the fragment will be handled by the browser.  To distinguish register and login pages instead use different [paths](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) in the URL.